# How can I fix "support fragment manager does not contain a definition for findfragmentbyid"

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

Am following a tutorial that uses support fragment manager when initialising google maps but I get this error "supportfragmetmanager does not contain a definition for FindFragmentById", any help??

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, Instead of SupportFragmentManager, i had used the supportmapfragment when casting 
`SupportMapFragment mapfragment = (SupportMapFragment)SupportMapFragment.FindFragmentById(Resource.Id.map);`

but it is supposed to be
`SupportMapFragment mapfragment = (SupportMapFragment)SupportFragmentManager.FindFragmentById(Resource.Id.map);`